# scaling data between -1 and 1 centred on zero

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Apologies in advance for any incorrect wording. The reason I am not finding answers to this might be because I am not using the right terminology.

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
0        -0.004973    0.008638   0.000264     -0.021122   -0.017193
1        -0.003744    0.008664   0.000423     -0.021031   -0.015688
2        -0.002526    0.008688   0.000581     -0.020937   -0.014195
3        -0.001322    0.008708   0.000740     -0.020840   -0.012715
4        -0.000131    0.008725   0.000898     -0.020741   -0.011249
5         0.001044    0.008738   0.001057     -0.020639   -0.009800
6         0.002203    0.008748   0.001215     -0.020535   -0.008368
7         0.003347    0.008755   0.001373     -0.020428   -0.006952
8         0.004476    0.008758   0.001531     -0.020319   -0.005554
9         0.005589    0.008758   0.001688     -0.020208   -0.004173
10        0.006687    0.008754   0.001845     -0.020094   -0.002809
...
```

For each column I would like to scale the data to a float between -1.0 and 1.0 for this column's min and max.
I have tried scikit learn's minmax scaler with `scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (-1, 1))` but some values change sign as a result, which I need to preserve.

Is there a way to 'centre' the scaling on zero?

Comment: I'm only showing a sample of the dataframe, all columns have both positive and negative values

Comment: I see you have negative and positive values. You want to keep the 0 point? In that case just divide the negative numbers with the minimum of the df (or row, or column whichever you want to normalise) and the positives with the maximum.

Comment: thank you @GáborErdős that might just do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `StandardScaler` from sklearn ?

It has `with_mean` and `with_std` option, which you can use to get data you want.

Comment: But that would results in the occasional value bigger (smaller) than 1 (-1). Perhaps using `StandardScaler` followed by a `MinMaxScaler`?

Comment: if we use 4*sgima = 1, then with_std = `1/4`. then i believe it will no cross 1 to -1 boundary that much

Comment: Could work I guess, dunno if that will be good enough for the OP.

Comment: thank you @kppatel, could you clarify how I would use `4*sgima = 1` and `with_std = 1/4` ? the latter is used as argument to standard scaler but the former?

Comment: if you take `4*sigma`  = 1, that means your 99.9999998% of your observation will fall under -1 to 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem with scaling the negative values to the column's minimum value and the positive values to the column's maximum value is that the scale of the positive numbers may be different than the scale of the positive numbers. If you want to use the same scale for both negative and positive values, try the following:

```
def zero_centered_min_max_scaling(dataframe):
    """
    Scale the numerical values in the dataframe to be between -1 and 1, preserving the
    signal of all values.
    """
    df_copy = dataframe.copy(deep=True)
    for column in df_copy.columns:
        max_absolute_value = df_copy[column].abs().max()
        df_copy[column] = df_copy[column] / max_absolute_value
    return df_copy
```